# Trouble to install "SQL Server Management Studio 2008" & VS 3.5 framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, frameworks

Yesterday i had problem with connecting SQL server 2005 with VS 2010, then i download "SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU" (SQL server Management Studio 2008) from Microsoft's website, now it asks for .NET 3.5 Framework. and when i tried to Install 3.5 framework, it again throw error. i think it comes because i already have 4.0 Framework in my PC and we can overlap with 3.5, any guess???

Comment: Please provide error messages

Comment: It says i need to install ".NET 3.5 SP1 framework"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 3.5 and 4 should run well side by side. Maybe there's some error in installer or your .Net installation.

Here are people with similar problem

http://forums.iis.net/p/1165685/1941233.aspx#1941233

They advice to change some key in the registry

If this fails, try to download SSMS 2008 R2 or 2005. Both are free, and 2005 doesn't use .NET 3.5